# iOS: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core)

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

I'm experiencing this error when building my Flutter app on iOS (it works fine on Android):

```
MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core))
```

I've searched and have seen this error in several places on this forum, but the solutions are all specific to Android, not iOS. I'm at a loss.

Here is my pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  firebase_core: ^1.10.0
  firebase_database: ^9.0.4
  firebase_analytics: ^9.0.4
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.1
  flutter_gallery_assets: ^1.0.2
  firebase_storage: ^10.2.0  
  permission_handler: ^8.3.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.4
  flutter_cupertino_localizations: ^1.0.1
  http: ^0.13.4
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  provider: ^6.0.1
  flappy_search_bar: ^1.7.2
  flutter_form_builder: ^7.0.0
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+4
  camera: ^0.9.4+5
  path_provider: ^2.0.7
  path: 


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
grinder: ^0.8.4
```

I've run `flutter doctor`, `flutter clean`, and `flutter pub get`. I've removed and performed a fresh install of the app. I updated Firebase to the latest version.

Here's where I'm calling Firebase and where the error pops up:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(MaterialApp(
      title: "Using Tabs",
      home: MyHome()));
}
```

For kicks, I implemented this solution in build.gradle as well, though it appears to be Android-specific, not iOS:

```
buildTypes {       
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
    }
}
```

If anyone has any thoughts, it's much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you correctly register the GeneratedPluginRegistrant in your AppDelegate ?
Since Firebase is using some native platform calls, this line is required.

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase
import FlutterPluginRegistrant


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {

     var flutterEngine : FlutterEngine?

     override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
         // Instantiate Flutter engine
         self.flutterEngine = FlutterEngine(name: "fullScreenEngineId")
         self.flutterEngine?.run()
         GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self.flutterEngine!)

         return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions) 
     }

}
```